# How to find duplicate combinations of columns across two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to find duplicates across two tables which are identified as a combination of five different columns. The tables have one similar column in common. My table structure and relevant columns look like the following:

### order_item_tbl

| EVENT_KEY | ORDER_KEY | ORDER_NBR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 82 | 1 |
| 14 | 82 | 2 |
| 14 | 82 | 3 |
| 14 | 82 | 1 |

### invoice_tbl

| EVENT_KEY | CUSTOMER_KEY | BOOTH_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 41 | 12 |
| 14 | 41 | 12 |

I've tried this query so far and everything is duplicated more than expected:

```
SELECT OI.ORDER_NBR AS ORDER_NBR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM ORDER_ITEM_TBL OI 
  JOIN INVOICE_TBL I
    ON I.EVENT_KEY = OI.EVENT_KEY
WHERE OI.EVENT_KEY = '14' AND OI.ORDER_KEY = '82'
AND I.BOOTH_KEY = '12' AND I.CUSTOMER_KEY = '41' AND OI.ORDER_NBR in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY OI.ORDER_NBR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Based on this dataset I would expect to receive the following result:

| ORDER_NBR | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

However this is the result I'm seeing:

| ORDER_NBR | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The invoice table has the same row twice. Joining on that will duplicate the rows (remove the grouping to see what's happening). Then counting over them will count those duplicate rows. If you only want to know if at least one row exists in the invoice table, you can use `where exists (select * from invoice_tbl where I.EVENT_KEY = OI.EVENT_KEY AND I.BOOTH_KEY = '12' AND I.CUSTOMER_KEY = '41' )`, instead of the join.

Comment: @GolezTrol I do now see that the join is causing the duplicates, but I'm not sure I'm following you on the last bit. I want to know how many times the combination of the five columns occurs. If I'm understanding you correctly, are you saying this query will do that?

```SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INVOICE_TBL I
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ORDER_ITEM_TBL OI WHERE I.EVENT_KEY = OI.EVENT_KEY AND 
OI.EVENT_KEY = '14' AND OI.ORDER_KEY = '82'
AND I.BOOTH_KEY = '12' AND I.CUSTOMER_KEY = '41' AND OI.ORDER_NBR in (1,2,3,4,5))```

Comment: It is not clear why you need the second table because the first one (`order_item_tbl`) is sufficient to get the output you expect. Please provide more sample data with other `event_id` and their corresponding output

Answer (score 0):

group by ORDER_NBR alone must give you the results i reckon as you have only ORDER_NBR in select .

The same query will not execute in posgres , as psql requires columns in group by to be in select or in aggregate funcations

Comment: Yes you're right, I just edited my main post to reflect that. Still getting the same result though.